# Convergence of sequence of stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $\psi$ be a sequence of progressively measurable processes s.t. for all $t \ge 0$ we have: $\psi_t^n\to0$ a.s. Let B be a standard brownian motion.

Assume also that there exists a process $\phi\in \lambda^2_{loc}$ with $|\psi^n|\le \phi$. Where $\lambda^2_{loc}$ is the set of {$\phi:$ $\phi_s$ is progressive and $\int_0^t\phi_s^2ds< \infty$ for all t}

How could I show that for $t>0$ $$\int_0^t\psi^n_sdB_s\to0$$
in probability?

What is making it hard for me is that $\phi$ is not surely integrable and therefore I cannot apply Lebesgue theorem.

I will provide my attempt, I would really appreciate a feedback.

Let's divide the problem in two cases:

$1)$ assume $E[\int_0^t\phi^2_sds]<\infty$

Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}E\bigg[ (\int_0^t\psi^n_sdB_s-0)^2\bigg]=\lim_{n \to \infty}E\bigg[ \int_0^t(\psi^n_s)^2ds\bigg]\to0$$
by dominated convergenge theorem, since both $\int_0^t(\psi^n_s)^2ds<\int_0^t(\phi_s)^2ds$ and $(\psi^n_s)^2<\phi_s^2$ and both $\phi_s^2$ and $\int_0^t(\phi_s)^2ds$ are integrable by our initial assumption.

$2)$ Assume now instead that $\tau_k$ is a sequence of stopping time defined as $$\tau_k:inf(t\ge0:\int_0^t\phi^2_sds\ge k)$$
 Now:
For a $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists a $k$ s.t. $P(t > \tau_k)<\epsilon$

For $a >0$

$$\begin{align*} P(|\int_0^t\psi^n_sdB_s - 0|>a) &= P(|\int_0^t\psi^n_sdB_s|>a;t<\tau_k)+P(|\int_0^t\psi^n_sdB_s|>a;t\ge \tau_k) \\ &\le P(|\int_0^t\psi^n_sdB_s|>a;t<\tau_k) + \epsilon \\ &\le
P(|\int_0^{t \land \tau_k}\psi^n_sdB_s|>a) \to0 \end{align*} $$

and the last step follow since, as before we could write:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}E\bigg[ (\int_0^{t \land \tau_k}\psi^n_sdB_s-0)^2\bigg]=\lim_{n \to \infty}E\bigg[ \int_0^{t \land \tau_k}(\psi^n_s)^2ds\bigg]\to0$

and
 $\int_0^{t \land \tau_k}(\psi^n_s)^2ds \le \int_0^{t \land \tau_k}\phi^2_sds$ and $(\psi^n_s)^2<\phi_s^2$ and both $\int_0^{t \land \tau_k}(\phi_s)^2s$ and $\phi_s^2$ (is it right that also $\phi_s^2$ is integrable under the inital assumption of step 2?)  are integrable by our initial assumption.

So what do you think about this proof? is it correct?

Comment: Isn't this just the same as the current edit of a previous question of yours?

Comment: @RhysSteele yes, actually it is, the fact is that otherwise no one would notice the old edit, and I would have spent time in vain. If you solve my doubt, also answering on the other post, i would delete this for order purposes